# 'cordova add platform android' with specific version

Tags: android, cordova

I want add android platform on cordova using specific version: android-10. I use 'gulp' with 'gulp-shell' to create cordova env, so it must be repeatable in command line for CI and CD.

Today when I run:

```
$ cordova platforms add android
```

It create in `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` file :

```
android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

I want `android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I specify the minimum SDK in phonegap? It is ignoring android-minsdkversion in config.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135185/how-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers)

Comment: I think your question title is misleading, because it seems to ask about a specific version of the android platform, not a min-sdk

Comment: You can also add directly from the repo: `cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android.git#7.1.0`

Answer (score 69):

Try to check here what is the list of Android Platforms  => [Cordova Android Platforms](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/)

and try to use:

```
cordova platform add android@x.x.x
```

replacing x.x.x with the version that you need

A [list of released version can be found on github](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/releases).

Comment: This is good for the right version of the android plugin, but it doesnt affect the min version of the default manifest once the app is added.

Comment: for example `android@4.1.1`

Comment: For Android 6 we need to use `android@6.3.0`. I figured this out by trial and error. Is there a list where this is documented?

Answer (score 15):

In your cordova project's config.xml, add an android platform section:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
</platform>
```

This way each time you build, it will get added to the android manifest, instead of getting overwritten each time you rebuild.

If you want to target a newer platform than 19, then you can use a second preference:

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

A trick if you don't known which x.x.x release is available, request only the master version. E.g. :

```
cordova add platform android@4
```

, will install the next available 4.x.x release. today 4.1.1.

Enjoy

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

The command to add a specific version of android platform via cordova is:

```
 cordova platform add android@VERSION
```

eg.

```
cordova platform add android@8
```

Answer (score -6):

Change the `AndroidManifest.xml` maually. Open that file in any editor. Then set your choices.

```
android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

And build the project

```
$ cordova build android
```

Goal

Comment: I want know if cordova command has any argument to do that, or any other command exists.

Comment: This will also get overwritten if the platform is ever removed, or even when building through the CLI

Comment: Editing the platform folder manually is a non-permanent nor portable solution, since the platform folder can be removed or added at any time; the Cordova project should handle this correctly, so the project can be shared more easily.

Comment: platform folder might be removed.