# Phonegap Online build for specific android version

Tags: android, version, phonegap-build

Online build for my phonegap (3.7.0) application always targets the latest version of android. My config.xml file clearly specifies the following

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="8" /> 
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="8" />
```

Yet the build log response is

```
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level:        21
```

Am uploading only the source www and config.xml. Is there anything here that am doing wrong ?

Comment: did you add the preferences in  (<platform name="android">   ... </platform>)  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135185/how-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers

Comment: In addition, SDK below 10 is NOT supported.

Comment: @tasos - Tried your suggestion. Changed config,xml same with <platform name="android"> .. </platform>, this time specifying SDK 10 but no use.   The online build always seems to build only for latest android target i.e Project Target:   Android 5.0.1 in this case.