# Can you explain me or refer to concern article How a higher version android app is working on lower version

Tags: android, cordova

Below is in my config file

```
  <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="23" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

Value 23 target Android 6.0 version but app working fine in Android 5.1 and few features like Cordova Barcode Scanner not working in 4.4.2

Kindly explain

Comment: minsdk is the property which u shud look for

Comment: if it says minsdk 23 then it will require atleast 23

Comment: @Rico if I dont set minSdkVersion. Will my app work for all android version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set minSdkVersion in your android application.

Here are some ref. that may help you.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135185/how-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers)

[Link 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html)

Comment: if I dont set minSdkVersion. Will my app work for all android version?

Comment: May be it's works but it leads several major issue such as if some of method/functions are  depreciated in old versions then your app may be stops after and test period increase due increase number of API although old API not in use. So we have to choose some appropriate min sdk as well as max sdk sdk as requirement of our target audience.

Comment: U know my previous developer not used minsdk that's y I was wondering how it works apart from tagersdk

Comment: I already told you bro without setting min sdk it works but arise issues, if you think about long term.

Comment: Got it. Arigato

Comment: it explains well here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: yeah bro ... @Mani