# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:wikitudesdk:]

Tags: android, xml, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap, wikitude

Someone please help me. I am trying to rebuild it. I have added a new plugin and assets. But when I am trying to rebuild the project, it shows this error. I've already changed the min SDK in /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml to 19 but it was changed to default which is SDK 14.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.986 secs

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\kristelle\Desktop\AULocation\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-74 Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:wikitudesdk:] C:\Users\kristelle\Desktop\AULocation\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\wikitudesdk\AndroidManifest.xml
        Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.wikitude.architectandlib" to force usage

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:wikitudesdk:] C:\Users\kristelle\Desktop\AULocation\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\wikitudesdk\AndroidManifest.xml
  >       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.wikitude.architectandlib" to force usage
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135185/how-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same sort of problem. I think your build.gradle file for the wikitudesdk library is set to use 14

```
defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 14
     targetSdkVersion ...
}
```

try changing it to:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion ...
}
```

I ended up checking each build.gradle file in my project. I also made sure to **remove** the `<uses-sdk.../>` in each project AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="..." />
```

I think the two settings in `<uses-sdk.../>` `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are suppose to be inserted into the manifest from the build.gradle settings.

Hope that helps.