# How can I specify cordova android version in config.xml?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to use a specific version of cordova android (lets say 6.2.2).
I know it can be done by this command :

> cordova add platform android@6.2.2

But I want to know if there is way to just add platform and the version to put it inside the xml.

I have seen also this question [How can I specify the minimum SDK in phonegap? It is ignoring android-minsdkversion in config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135185/how-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers) 
but I cannot figure out how it can be possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done using the `<engine>` tag:

```
<engine name="android" spec="^6.3.0" />
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.1" />
<engine name="browser" spec="latest" />
```

You can find the docs for it [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/config_ref/index.html#engine).

Comment: what does the ^ sign mean? let's say i want to build apk to support android version 5 or higher. so what will be the spec value?

Comment: ^ before the version means it will update to the next minor version when available (and ~ means to the next patch version)